# Is it possible to update security groups, via javascript, by reading a json file instead of using parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I want to update security group rules by having my javascript file read the information from a separate json file instead of having to use json parameters.

Now that I've used json parameters to update security groups, I've started to learn about updating with a json file by having javascript/node.js read the file.

This is a proposed code I've used:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

var fs = require('fs');

var filename = 'sg-0136a8e42bc076309Ingress.json';

var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'});

ec2.updateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsIngress(filename, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Failed to retrieve information", err);
        return; 
    }
    console.log("Information updated!");

    fs.readFile(filename, (err, data) => {
        if(err) console.log("Failed to output into file", err);
    });

});
```

Here are the JSON parameters:

```
GroupId: "sg-0136a8e42bc076309",
IpPermissions: [
    {
        FromPort: 139,
        IpProtocol: "tcp",
        IpRanges: [
            {
                CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0",
                Description: "NetBIOS Session Service"
            }
        ],
        ToPort: 139
    }
]
```

But, as a result, I only received an error message:

```
Failed to retrieve information { MultipleValidationErrors: There were 34 validation errors:
* InvalidParameterType: Expected params to be a structure
* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'IpPermissions' in params
```

That's an example of the error. How can I update security groups by means of having javascript read the json file without having an error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not write the name of the file in the variable `var filename = 'sg-0136a8e42bc076309Ingress.json'` and set it as a parameter of the `ec2.updateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsIngress` function. You can just require JSON file and give as a parameter to function

```js
var file = require("./sg-0136a8e42bc076309Ingress.json");
ec2.updateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsIngress(file, function(err, data) {
     if (err) {
         console.log("Failed to retrieve information", err);
         return; 
     }
     console.log("Information updated!");
});
```

In addition, one more thing your, in this case, your function `fs.readFile` is useless.

Comment: I ran that updated code you've provided, but this is what I got: